# How do you align SF Symbols with one another in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiimage, sf-symbols

In the WWDC SF Symbols video, Apple says to prefer horizontal and vertical alignment when displaying SF Symbols. Presumably, that means that each `UIImageView.center.x` should contain the same value so that they line up in a column. My question is how to determine what that x value should be since they are all different widths. Here is an example screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

This screenshot is using `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` with `cell.imageView` and `cell.textLabel`. However, I want to know how to achieve the same effect using a custom `UITableViewCell`. Is the correct way to just determine a certain amount of width based off the `UIImageSymbolConfiguration.pointSize`? Once you have that width, all symbols will be displayed according to that center?

Any guidance on how to layout/align SF Symbols especially without the use of auto layout would be super helpful :)

Comment: Give your image view your desired width, and then set the Content Mode of your image view to **Center** ... `myImageView.contentMode = .center`

Comment: Yes, but how do you know how wide to make the image view? Or how to position the text so that the cells line up together?

Comment: That's generally done with auto-layout... I don't really understand your comment: *"especially without the use of auto layout"*?

Comment: Are you planning on designing your cell as a Storyboard Prototype? Or via code only?

Comment: I am doing it in code only. Using `layoutSubviews` for positioning

Comment: There has to be some amount of width given to the icons, because each table view cell is encapsulated yes? Is it possible to get the max width of a symbol at a point size/scale?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple example.

It loops through the data to determine the widest symbol that will be used to set the imageView's width constraint constant.

```
class MySymbolCell: UITableViewCell {

    let symbolImageView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.contentMode = .center
        return v
    }()
    let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        return v
    }()

    var imageWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        symbolImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        contentView.addSubview(symbolImageView)
        contentView.addSubview(theLabel)

        // this way we can change imageView width at run-time if needed
        imageWidthConstraint = symbolImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0)
        imageWidthConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)

        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // constrain imageView top / bottom / leading
            symbolImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            symbolImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            symbolImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),

            // constrain width
            imageWidthConstraint,

            // constrain height equal to width
            symbolImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: symbolImageView.widthAnchor),

            // constrain label leading 8-pts from image view
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: symbolImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 8.0),

            // constrain label centerY to image view centerY
            theLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: symbolImageView.centerYAnchor),

            // constrain label trailing to content view trailing
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),

        ])
    }
}

class MySymbolTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var myData: [String] = [
        "arrow.up",
        "arrow.down",
        "person.badge.plus",
        "eye.slash",
        "line.horizontal.3",
        "textformat.123",
    ]

    var symbolImageViewWidth: CGFloat = 40.0

    // configure as desired
    let imageConfig = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 20, weight: .light, scale: .default)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // calculate how wide you need your cell's symbol image view to be

        // either run a loop to get the widest symbol your data is using,
        //  or
        // just make sure you can fit the widest of the symbols ("bold.italic.underline")

        let testLoop = true

        if testLoop {

            var maxW: CGFloat = 0.0
            myData.forEach {
                if let img = UIImage(systemName: $0, withConfiguration: imageConfig) {
                    maxW = max(img.size.width, maxW)
                }
            }
            symbolImageViewWidth = maxW

        } else {

            if let img = UIImage(systemName: "bold.italic.underline", withConfiguration: imageConfig) {
                symbolImageViewWidth = img.size.width
            }

        }

        tableView.register(MySymbolCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MySymbolCell")

    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MySymbolCell", for: indexPath) as! MySymbolCell

        let img = UIImage(systemName: myData[indexPath.row], withConfiguration: imageConfig)

        cell.symbolImageView.image = img
        cell.theLabel.text = myData[indexPath.row]

        cell.imageWidthConstraint.constant = symbolImageViewWidth

        return cell
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help here! Is `bold.italic.underline` the widest symbol?

Comment: Yes - at least for now. I suppose it's possible that in a future update Apple could add a new symbol, but my assumption is that you know what symbols (or at least what set of symbols) you'll be using.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to adjust cell.separatorInset

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
```